# creating C-library stubs in raspberry pie bare metal programming

Tags: c, bare-metal

I am currently working with raspberry pie and following a well written chapter 2 tutorial on [Chap 2 of valvers.com](http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step02-bare-metal-programming-in-c-pt2/). I managed to understand everything but I am little stuck on the last section titled "C-Library stubs". In that I am facing some doubts which i mentioned below:

```
    #include <sys/stat.h>

/* A helper function written in assembler to aid us in allocating memory */
extern caddr_t _get_stack_pointer(void);

/* Increase program data space. As malloc and related functions depend on this,
   it is useful to have a working implementation. The following suffices for a
   standalone system; it exploits the symbol _end automatically defined by the
   GNU linker. */
caddr_t _sbrk( int incr )
{
    extern char _end;
    static char* heap_end;
    char* prev_heap_end;

    if( heap_end == 0 )
        heap_end = &_end;

     prev_heap_end = heap_end;

     if( ( heap_end + incr) > _get_stack_pointer() )
     {
        while(1)
        {
            /* TRAP HERE! */
        }
     }

     heap_end += incr;
     return (caddr_t)prev_heap_end;
}
```

so far i have only understood that this is the implementation of _sbrk function.

**1).** I am not able to understand what exactly this code does in reference to the tutorial given in link?

**2).** The other thing that i am not able to understand is common in armc-008c and 009c i.e. why and how we are changing from main function to kernel_main function? the only text available for this mentions that

> NOTE: We've now changed from main to kernel_main, and there's a reason for this - the bootloader is actually expecting a slightly different entry definition compared to the standard C main function. So as we're setting up our own C-Runtime anyway, we can define the correct entry format

I am a beginner in C and these may sound noobish questions but I have did lots of research and spent 3 to 4 days on same tutorial before asking this question here. I am still trying to understand logic behind these programs. Can you guys shed some light over this issue. It will be much more than just help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Specification of your question could help increasing the change of a good answer.

Comment: Specification as in you want some more details about my question? or you want me to reduce the details i have given?

Comment: Second, be more specific

Comment: I have edited my question and reduced some details. Does it looks clean now? thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I took a fast look to the tutorial link, it seems low level stuff, good to learn and know about but not really used on *every day* C programming, if you are a C beginner may be better you look for some easier tutorial first.

Comment: Thank you alex. Yea, those tutorials are little tricky for me to understand at this beginning level. But I have taken a task from my professor and right now working on same so he gave me that link and asked me to understand it as much as I can. I am going really slow and trying to resolve each and everything before moving up.

Comment: General advice: *Don't try to learn C and kernel-space programming at the same time.* Do *first* practice C until you are *at least* confident at it, *then* go "freestanding" (a.k.a. "bare metal"). Greetings from a former [OSDev](http://osdev.org) regular.

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you for your advice. You are absolutely right and I shall put your view in serious consideration. since I have already taken up this project I am only trying to explore how low level programming is done. As you said prior to moving further I will definitely make my C understanding very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_sbrk` function in your question is trying to *increase* the *extern* symbol `_end` allowing the application to [malloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Heap-based) more memory. (It doesn't directly increment `_end` but return the incremented value, `heap_end` declared as *static* preserve the value through multiple `_sbrk` calls)

<del>(Personally I've some doubt this `_sbrk` implementation have ever been tested, `_end` declared as *char* not *pointer* (* is missing) is suspect and `heap_end` assumed to be initialized to 0)</del>

About `main` and `kernel_main`, almost every C code need an *entry point*, for common *libc* application is `main` (is a libc convention), but as the quote say in this case a *bootloader* is used and it expect (looks for) a `kernel_main` symbol to jump into (a bootloader usually doesn't use the libc). The real entry point for (at least gcc) compilers is `_start` but libc hide it and use it to prepare the *environment* to launch the application, may be [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/hello_from_a_libc_free) help you understand how it work.

Comment: As far as your explanation is concerned, I am somewhat able to understand what is happening. Thank you very much.

Comment: The definition of _end is correct. As the comment says, it is defined by the linker. &_end gets that value.